# Como funciona a função inversa no jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu criei este código e estou tentando fazer a função inversa, ou seja, se estiver fechado, abre, se estiver aberto fecha. Estou tendo problemas e não vejo nada na console. Podem me ajudar?

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
$("#edit_prod").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ////////////////////////////////
    var code = $(this).data("forms");
    $(".formsEditProdutos").addClass("esconde");
    $(".formsEditProdutos").attr("id", code).removeClass("esconde");

}, function(event){

    var code = $(this).data("forms");
    $(".formsEditProdutos").attr("id", code).addClass("esconde");

});
```

Comment: O `click` não aceita duas funções. Vejo que estás a mudar a ID a cada click, parece-me estranho, acho que há maneiras melhor de fazer isso... Podes explicar o que queres fazer?

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML desse `#edit_prod` e de `.formsEditProdutos`? Aí posso dar uma sugestão de como seria melhor fazer isso.

Answer (score 5):

Tente usar o método `toggleClass`. Usando ele, se a classe estiver presente, ele remove, e se não estiver presente, ele adiciona.

```
 $(".formsEditProdutos").toggleClass("esconde");
```